# C++ wchar_t* not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wchar-t, wchar

```
    wchar_t* Pfad;
    wcin >> Pfad;

wchar_t* file = Pfad + "*.quiz";
```

Not working for me, how can I make this work?
It says `"*.quiz"` is wrong, something like it has to be a numeric value or something like that.

Well sorry, I am new to c++...

and my actual problem is, I use this, but I want to user to select the path

something like cin >> file

but I don't want the user to have to type "*.quiz";

```
wchar_t* file = L"C:/Users/Niku/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Quiz/Quiz/Fragen_Niko/*.quiz"; 
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
 HANDLE hFind;
hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData); 

if( hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
max++;
while ((x = FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData)) == TRUE)
max++;
}
```

If I use anything else besides wchar_t* it's not working..

Comment: You are not ready, use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: Also, wide-character string literals are prefixed with an L, like this: `L"*.quiz"`

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191)

Comment: This is _obviously_ not a duplicate of a list of books. Stupid people.

Comment: Short answer: Adding two pointers (`Pfad` and `"*.quiz"`) isn't going to produce anything useful. You need to use a concatenation function to concatenate the string referenced by those pointers, or you need a class that overrides `+` to provide concatenation (aformentioned `wstring`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working the way you are expecting because you don't fully understand *pointers* and string literals in C++. If you want to know what's wrong, please [pick any of these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1) (possibly beginner ones).

If you want to fix this problem straight ahead (take a shortcut) use an [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead:

```
std::wstring Pfad;
std::wcin >> Pfad;
auto file = Pfad + L"*.quiz";
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c397d0941bb6799)

As suggested by [Rook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1450890/rook), if you have to pass a pointer to C APIs you can use the member function [`std::wstring::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), which will return a `const wchar_t*` for you to use.

Comment: You should probably mention `.c_str()`, as well. It'll be needed to feed to those winapi functions in the  OP.

Comment: Well thank you, but the problem is, if I use wstring in the line "hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData);" I get an error "file - ERROR: std::wstring to LPCWSTR"

Comment: @user3566608, try with `hFind = FindFirstFile(file.c_str(), &FindFileData);`.

Comment: Thank you! The errors are gone, but if I cin my path "C:/Users/Niku/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Quiz/Quiz/Fragen_Niko/" it doesn't work. It says "there are 0 files" with the my old code it works. Maybe it's because of the blanks (/Visual Studio 2012/) ? Sorry for asking, but do you know how I could make this work?

However, thank you, you helped me a lot!